# Django Admin panel interface

Tags: python, django

To create admin interface to edit some field, which is best practice? Customize default Django admin or create admin template?

I want to edit `status` field via admin. But others field, admin can't edit.. In this scenario can I write new view and template for admin or just customize the default admin panel?

```
class SendProduct(models.Model):
    PAYMENT_CHOICE = (
        ('A', 'Advanced'),
        ('C', 'COD'),
    )
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_details = models.TextField()
    delivery_address = models.TextField()
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICE)
    payable_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    delivery_charge = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qrcode', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: How is build the model you want to adapt ? you should add it if you want efficient help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding fields and make them read-only(`admin.py`). An example is given below

```
class SendProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude=("item_name ",)
    readonly_fields=('item_name', )

admin.site.register(SendProductAdmin)
```

Note that you can exclude as many fields as you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between the usage of admin panel and the views that you develop, the difference that you should pay attention is the admin panel is for `staff users`, the users that are inside company and organization and provide content to the end-users.

So who is going to work with that form? Decide on that base and what you want to do can be done both in admin panel and a developed view.

Comment: I have added my model. I want to edit status via admin. But others field, admin can't edit.. In this scenario can I write new view and template for admin or just customize the default admin panel?

Comment: You need to restrict your admin panel for some users? So they can only edit some of fields?

Comment: You cannot do that in ordinary way, just a tricky way, define a new model class as proxy of your current class and do restriction on it, that give access to that instead of your primary model

Comment: Or you can just set **fields** in your current admin, but in that case, anyone else cannot edit extra fields